# Convert list to strings to read max

Tags: python, list, file, int, max

I am trying to convert this file i converted into a list to read an interger so it can read the max of the list. this is what i have so far.

```
file=open(steps.txt,'r')
    inlist = list(file)
    for x in inlist:
        print(x,end="")
```

Comment: That was a misprint, excuse the main

Comment: Please clarify your question, and share at least part of the data. _this is what i have so far._ Alright, so what is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is just a bit wrong

```
file=open('steps.txt','r')
inlist = list(file)
for x in inlist:
    print(x,end="")
file.close()
```

steps.txt needs to get into ''

However with this you can read the values, however to read the max you need to split the string and change the type of the value to int.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: i would suggest you read the file file for file, what is the format of the file, just numbers and caps or are there any other symbols